# match and merge node in a loop

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a relationship between 2 nodes where both the codes are in loop.But its creating multiple relationships.

Eg:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:User), (p:Page)
WHERE n.id in["1","2","3"] AND p.id in ["10","12","13"]
MERGE (n)-[:likes]->(p)
```

The result above connects 1 to 10,12,13 and 2 to 10,12,13 and 3 to 10,12,13.But in reality I want only 3 relationships .I want 1 to connect to 10 ,2 connect to 12 and 3 connect to 13.How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UNWIND [[1,10],[2,12],[3,13]] as pair
MATCH (n:User), (p:Page)
WHERE n.id = pair[0] AND p.id = pair[1]
MERGE (n)-[:likes]->(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:User), (p:Page)
WHERE (n.id=="1" AND p.id="10") OR (n.id=="2" AND p.id="12") OR (n.id=="3" AND p.id="13")
MERGE (n)-[:likes]->(p)
```

Your condition is true for all combinations. Instead you should explicitly allow only the desired ones.

For a small amount of combinations this approach is fine. For more the answer from Michael scales better.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Added an explanation